# Backbone Models - Working with Local related Json files

Tags: json, backbone.js, backbone-relational

I have multiple JSON files that I want to use as data sources for my models. The json files are related to each other with id's. Eg. { "movies" : [1,4,3] } in cinemas.json is related to "movies.json" with movieId's 1,4,3. I would like to preserve this relation while fetching/parsing the json files. Is there a way in which I can have movie models get instantiated automatically on fetching the "cinemas.json" based on the id's? How can I set this up? I tried using backbone-relational but am unable to figure out the proper setup. I asked a question about it too here :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066386/backbone-relational-multiple-related-local-json-files-collections

But I'm not sure if I should be chasing BB-Relational more. Maybe there's a better simpler way of doing this.

Appreciate the help!